# Fastest way to crawl Twitter data with Python - Followers' followers

Tags: python, twitter, web-crawler, social-networking, tweepy

I'm doing a research on user social relations in Twitter, in Python.

The problem is that "what is the fastest way to crawl followers of a certain user's followers information"
I searched a lot of information and am currently using Tweepy:

```
c = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, id=centre, count=5000).items()
    while True:
        try:
            followers_ids_list.append(c.next())
        except tweepy.TweepError:
            # hit rate limit, sleep for 15 minutes
            time.sleep(15 * 60 + 15)
            continue
```

and after that I am using the /users/lookup to find the User() object according to those ids gained before.

However, this way is quite slow...I was wondering if there any fastest than what I am doing currently.

Because I want to find the user relations, which means followers in depth 2 is not enough.

Say, I have 100 followers, and those 100 followers have their own 200 followers, then the time needed for grabbing this social network (depth=3) would be:

(1 + 100 + 100*200)/15calls * 15mins / 60mins = 335 hours = about 14 days!

- 1 call: request my follower ids (100ids)
- 100 calls: request 100 followers' followers ids (100*200ids)
- 100*200 calls(at least): request 100*200(followers' followers) users's ids.

What I can think about to be alternative is to crawl the twitter.com website without api (but, I figure, this way would make my IP or account banned from Twitter....)

Answer (score 0):

The API Limits prevent you from going any faster.

You could set up multiple apps and distribute the problem through them - but that's likely to get noticed by Twitter if they're all running from the same IP address.

Comment: Thank you so much for quick answer!

Comment: What are the current IP limits?

Answer (score 0):

You can never do it with Twitter API because of the 15 minutes time rate.

I'm also doing some work related to one author's followers. However, I need millions of followers' names, which is even worse.

My solution is to write my own crawler and it does work faster than API. It could crawl 100*1000 per night. (I test it on my local machine) This rate is lower than my expectation so I have to think about other ways to increase its speed. 
Hope this could give you some inspirations.

Comment: So you wrote your own http crawler that runs on twitter? Doesn't twitter prevent you from doing that?

Comment: @LetsPlayYahtzee Yes, I set a random sleep time between the time sending requests to Twitter. I also tried some free IP proxies but  most of them didn't work. So I set 3 computers and run the crawler. It's pretty good and I can extract about 3000*1000 per computer per night.

Comment: I tried to crawl using Http crawler, but there is Rate Limit, too. but the rate limits are different than API limits

Comment: @ Vahid K. Sure, my way is to give some random sleep time after 50(you can test  the number) times crawling. I also use different IP proxy when one IP was blocked. These tricks can avoid the crawling blocked.